# How to query historical prices where there are no initial dates nor end dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make a SQL query to find the product that has raised the least amount of money, but I'm facing a problem, and it is that I have a table which keeps track of different dates for prices, for example Product 1 has a price of 5000 for all the recipts  purchased between 2011-01-01 and the next date of a price change and that is 2012-01-01, on the other hand Product 1 has the latest price date as 2015-01-01 and its price is 5600, so it means that any recipt purchased from 2015-01-01 to an actual date has a price of 5600.

Here is a SQL Fiddle of the current problem:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62ec25/9

And the query I did to get an aproximation to the answer:

```
select pr.productName, sum(d.quantity*p.price)
from details d, product pr, price p, recipts r
where d.Product_ref=pr.ref
and pr.ref=p.Product_ref
and r.numRecipt=d.Recipts_numRecipt
group by pr.productName
order by 2 asc;
```

I'm pretty sure the query is wrong because I'm not taking into consideration the historical price for each product, but I cannot find a way to make use of the "in between" SQL operator, How can I get the expected result?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Either, Mysql for the fiddle and postres for my real example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd want to get your `price` table into a structure that looks like:

`| product_ref | price | startDate | endDate |`

Then build a query that joins on that table where the purchase date is between the price date range:

```
SELECT
  pr.productName,
  SUM(d.quantity * p.price)
FROM
  details d
  INNER JOIN product pr ON d.product_ref = pr.ref
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT
      p.product_ref,
      p.price, 
      MIN(p.priceDate) AS StartDate,
      MIN(p1.priceDate) AS EndDate
    FROM price p
      LEFT JOIN price p1 ON p.product_ref = p1.product_ref
    WHERE
      p.priceDate < p1.priceDate
    GROUP BY p.product_ref, p.price
  ) p ON pr.ref = p.product_ref
  INNER JOIN recipts r ON r.numRecipt = d.recipts_numRecipt
WHERE
  r.dateOfPurchase >= p.startDate AND r.dateOfPurchase < p.endDate
GROUP BY pr.productName
```

Comment: I tried your query and the only right value I'm getting is the amount for ice cream which is 4400, the other values I get are wrong, there was only one cake purchased in all the time in recipt 4 at 2014-05-01 with price of 4400 and the query returns the total for cake 6500. When I change the < for <= I get the right value for cakes but no longer for ice cream or the other products

Comment: I made an update to the query, give it a try now. You should be able to make some tweaks to your liking.